# Is it better to wait more in this case?

Tags: interviewing

Some weeks ago after one of my job application I received an email from the hiring manager which was saying something like "Hi...,  we have looked through your application and we think it is good to talk and discuss with you about the opportunity". Then we have scheduled a day for the phone call. And when the day came I had a very positive phone interview with the same person who is the hiring manager who is also the technical leader of the whole thing(the top guy).

He mentioned that he will let me meet the team onsite face to face in two weeks. He said because of Covid 19 one of the guy was not in the country ect. But I dont remember whether he said they will contact me about the meeting in two weeks or I will meet them in two weeks.

Now the first week has passed and didn't hear anything. First I was very excited and motivated and I was getting ready for it but the first week passed and I became paranoid since I was not contacted and lost my motivation and stopped getting prepared. I thought if I were to be invited there in two weeks I would have received an email the first week.

Do you think I should wait one more week to remind him? At the same time I dont want to look pushy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 2):

If you're unclear about whether there should be a meeting or not, you should check in with the manager.

A short email asking for clarification should do.
Thank you emails for interviews are common anyway, but this seems beyond the usual time to reply, so I'd just mention my interest and ask for clarification about the meeting.

I don't see how that would be perceived as a negative, or "pushy".

On the other hand, not clarifying and thus missing the meeting that was supposed to happen definitely won't reflect well on you.

Comment: It is because only one week passed, He said in two weeks. Thats why Im not sure when to write.

Comment: " But I dont remember whether he said they will contact me about the meeting in two weeks or I will meet them in two weeks"
That's quite a difference. If you've agreed to meet them there, and don't show up, that would be awkward.

Comment: No I meant he would arrange the meeting or inform me about the meeting in two weeks(I dont remember which one he meant there I was excited). Thats what he said. So basically I supposed to wait and hear from them/him.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question a bit then. Either way, a short notice showing interest and asking for clarification will hardly hurt, and put your mind at ease.

I'd leave it at that, though

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to just treat this as normal, and not make a big deal out of it. You can always contact the company, and ask if they have already have an update for you. This is entirely reasonable to ask. Don't steer the question in any specific direction. You have a perfectly reasonable interest to ask, as you are legitimately looking around for a job and therefore need to manage your agenda.

If they have an update, great. If they don't have an update, you politely thank them for their continued interest and let them know that you'll look forward to their response at a future time.

Comment: Better the wait the two weeks over before writing? Because he said two weeks but I dont remember it was contacting in two weeks or me being onsite in two weeks.

Comment: @user1999: **Don't wait**. You don't need to give your reasons why you want an update now. If pressed, ask if they can already give a specific time, or at least date. As far as they know, you may have been asked by another company to interview as well (don't lie on this, stay silent on _why_ you want an update). You might also have other non-business reasons. Again, don't lie, but don't tell either.